# "No root filesystem is defined" while installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I have just got a new laptop,
It is running Windows 7 Home Premium.

I have shrunk the windows partition to give me some empty space and now I want to install ubuntu.

From Windows my partitions look like:
[image: My partitions]

So now in the ubuntu live cd If I hit install and go manual the partitioner looks like [image: My partitions in Ubuntu]

So I thought I could just select the empty space and be away laughing, but when I hit it I get

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From windows delete the empty partition (unallocated is probably the word they'd use for that so you are good to go).

Start the Ubuntu installation and when you get to the partitioner choose 'install on empty space' or use the manual partitioner to manually choose it (that way you can also set sizes for /, swap and, if need be, /home)

It will look like this:

[image]

Regarding the edit:

You MUST create a mountpoint for at least root.
See the / in this image:

[image]

From your situation: hit the line that says 'free space'. Create the partitions you need (root /, swap, home, data partition(s) etc) and then hit forward.

Comment: Ah, after your suggestion of setting sizes for the different parts I realized I had to setup both / and swap :) - will accept asap.

Comment: Great I added in a picture and will add some text now :D

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the  easiest way is to go back to start, meaning exent the windows partion to the whole disk. Than start to install ubuntu and choose in "Allocate drive space" the option 1 and everything else will be done automatically.

Comment: What's the difference with Rinzwinds answer (except that his answer is better?)

Comment: You are right Rinzwinds answer is better. However, as my start in ubuntu was hard as people gave me informations and hints which I now would evaluate as complicated from a beginners point of view, I offered my advice which would minimize the need of knowlegde. To explain, Hailwood knew how to change partitions. Therefore to go back to the beginning, everything just windows on the hd, he would know how to handle. Then starting the install of ubuntu and choose option 1, he would never ever face any problems. Offering to use the manual option is for a beginner tough.